Screen record Mac with computer audio and ambient audio soundtracks
I'm making a video trailer for a little arcade-style game that I'm putting up on Steam. This is not a major production, and I'm not going to spend a bunch of money on equipment. But it's a multiplayer game, and in my humble opinion the human sound effects are every bit as delightful as the game sound effects, as the kids yell and exclaim after hitting each other.
So: I want to screen record while recording BOTH computer audio (game sounds) AND ambient audio through the laptop's microphone. I can see how to merge the two streams using Loopback. But wouldn't it be nicer if I could record the two soundtracks separately and mix them later? So I'm looking for recommendations as to how this might be done – inexpensively, with software. By the way, I'm on a Mac.

OBS can screen record, record from a mic and record system sounds, and it's free.
Screenflow can also do this, isn't free, but is easier to use.
Zoom allows you to record system sounds and mic sounds during a call, which might be another free option.
Quicktime can screen record, and mic sounds, but not system sounds unless you use a workaround like soundflower or loopback. This is fiddly.
You could record ambient sounds from another source, eg Voice Memos on an iPhone, and re-sync the audio afterwards with a free video editor like DaVinci resolve or CapCut.
